# What select_expr clause in SELECT statements is good for?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

Could you explain what `select_expr` clause in `SELECT` statements is good for? I've been always using `*` for `select_expr` like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ...
```

and it was enough.

Comment: what if one of the column is a BIG BLOG, contains few hundred MB of data .. and you actually don't need this column?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

- You can *add* calculated columns: `select a, b, a+b FROM table`
- You can restrict the transferred data volume.
- You can give individual columns a new name.
- You can program more safely and performant.

Add to the first and second point: Especially usually require column restriction.

Add to the fourth point: When doing adhoc queries I'm almost always using `*`. But the programs should always enumerate the columns. This prevents surprising column reordering and also makes it clear what data is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

An example over and above the others already suggested:

- You need to use aggregate functions:

  ```
  SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS Num_Total
    FROM OrderItem
   GROUP BY OrderID;
  ```
- You need to get information from two parts of a UNION query.  I used this in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445856/15168) to another question recently:

  ```
  SELECT v1.ID AS OrderID_1, v1.NA AS NS, v2.ID AS OrderID_2, v2.NB AS NL, v3.NC AS NC
    FROM (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS NA
            FROM OrderItem
           WHERE OrderID = <specified order ID>
           GROUP BY OrderID
         ) AS v1
    JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS NB
            FROM OrderItem
           WHERE OrderID != <specified order ID>
           GROUP BY OrderID
         ) AS v2
      ON v1.NA <= v2.NB
    JOIN (SELECT I1.ID, COUNT(*) AS NC
            FROM OrderItem AS I1
            JOIN OrderItem AS I2 ON I2.ItemID = I1.ItemID AND I2.OrderID = <specified order ID>
           WHERE I1.OrderID != <specified order ID>
           GROUP BY I1.ID
         ) AS v3
      ON v3.ID = v2.ID
  UNION
  SELECT v2.ID AS OrderID_1, v2.NB AS NS, v1.ID AS OrderID_2, v2.NA AS NL, v3.NC AS NC
    FROM (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS NA
            FROM OrderItem
           WHERE OrderID = <specified order ID>
           GROUP BY OrderID
         ) AS v1
    JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS NB
            FROM OrderItem
           WHERE OrderID != <specified order ID>
           GROUP BY OrderID
         ) AS v2
      ON v1.NA > v2.NB
    JOIN (SELECT I1.ID, COUNT(*) AS NC
            FROM OrderItem AS I1
            JOIN OrderItem AS I2 ON I2.ItemID = I1.ItemID AND I2.OrderID = <specified order ID>
           WHERE I1.OrderID != <specified order ID>
           GROUP BY I1.ID
         ) AS v3
      ON v3.ID = v1.ID
  ```

At no point in that query was the `Quantity` column from the OrderItem table of any relevance to the computation I was doing.  There's no way to write that query without using the 'select_expr' rather than 'SELECT *'.  You might note that the initial 'aggregate function' suggestion is one of the sub-queries in this larger query (and it appears twice — you trust that the optimizer will optimize accurately).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your table has a million columns, you were only interested in one, and you were speaking to your database over a network via a 30 baud connection.

Comment: table has *million* of columns? wow that's huge.

Comment: It was only a thought experiment :) (typo corrected, thanks)