# Jaccard similarity computation in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I had the data like below:

```
CustomerId   Category
  100            2
  100            2
  100            3
  100            6
  100            4
  200            3
  200            6
  200            7
  300            2
```

So the output I want is the [Jaccard Similarity Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index):

- Jaccard(100,200) = 2 (items shared) / 5 (union of items)
- Jaccard(100,300) = 1 (items shared) / 4 (union of items)
- Jaccard(200,300) = 0 (items shared) / 4 (union of items).

What I tried initially is to find the Union and intersection of terms but I am not sure if it is the most efficient way. Also I want to avoid duplicates like Jaccard(100,300) and Jaccard(300,100) appearing together. Can someone help with this?

```
     select t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id,
              sum(case when t1.category_id = t2.category_id then 1 else 0 end) intersection,
sum(case when t1.category = t2.category then 1
         when t1.category <> t2.category then 1 else 0 end)
union
    from t t1 cross join
         t t2
  Where t1.customer_id <> t2.customer_id
    group by t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
```

Unfortunately I also checked that I have one customer buying multiple items in the same category. So I edited the table to reflect that Customer 100 has two items in Category 2. However, it should not change the Jaccard similarity metric values.

Comment: so the similarity for (100,200) should be 2/5..not 2/4..correct?

Comment: Use `t1.customer_id < t2.customer_id`; that avoids `(100,100)` and `(300,100)`.

Comment: I don't know whether [How to select similar sets in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132270/how-to-select-similar-sets-in-sql/) adds anything for you — probably not.

Comment: In Hive the above does not work as non-equality joins don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `cross join`. Get the denominator by computing the total of distinct category_id's for a pair and subtracting the intersecting category_id's from it.

```
SELECT t1.customer_id AS id1,
       t2.customer_id AS id2,
       1.0*sum(CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     / (count(DISTINCT t1.category_id)+count(DISTINCT t2.category_id)-sum(CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS jaccard_similarity
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 ON t1.customer_id<t2.customer_id
GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
```

If inequalities aren't supported in `join`, use

```
SELECT t1.customer_id AS id1,
       t2.customer_id AS id2,
       1.0*sum(CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       / (count(DISTINCT t1.category_id)+count(DISTINCT t2.category_id)-sum(CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS jaccard_similarity
FROM t t1
CROSS JOIN t t2 
WHERE t1.customer_id<t2.customer_id
GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
```

If you just need the intersection counts across pairs, the query below should suffice.

```
select t1.customer_id as id1, t2.customer_id as id2
,sum(case when t1.category_id = t2.category_id then 1 else 0 end) as intersection
from t t1 
join t t2 on t1.customer_id<t2.customer_id
group by t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
```

Edit: Based on OP's comment that a customer can have the same category multiple times but should be counted only once.

```
SELECT t1.customer_id AS id1,
       t2.customer_id AS id2,
       1.0*COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN t1.category_id END)
       / (COUNT(DISTINCT t1.category_id)+COUNT(DISTINCT t2.category_id)
         -COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t1.category_id = t2.category_id THEN t1.category_id END)) AS jaccard_similarity
FROM t t1
CROSS JOIN t t2 
WHERE t1.customer_id<t2.customer_id
GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id
```

Comment: what doesn't work? inequality in join? i edited the answer with a `cross join`..it should work

Comment: Yes, I guess I can use cross join with where condition?

Comment: the problem is Jaccard similarity comes out to > 1 actually in my case because I have same customer purchasing multiple items. I guess the intersection is not computed accurately.

Comment: @vkaul11 .. i edited the answer to count only distinct items per pair. this should give the expected results.